# If a person in a vacuum suit could fly without any sort of propulsion force could they exit and re-enter Earth’s atmosphere without burning up?

Tags: atmospheric-science, space

In a theoretical situation, say we have some sort of wizard who can fly with their mind. Let's say they can fly up to 40 m/s. So, this person wants to fly to the Moon, so they get on a space suit and fly straight up. Eventually, they exit Earth’s atmosphere, and get to the Moon. They then decide to come back. Could they, reaching Earth’s atmosphere once more, safely enter without a heat shield?

I am sketchy on why spaceships and other objects face burning up when reentering atmosphere. My belief is that it is because they are moving quite fast, and the friction of the atmosphere creates heat. If that is correct, then this should work.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on what your 40 m/s limit means and how it works. Also consider the orbital velocity of the moon is around 1 km/s so you might have trouble catching it with your 40 m/s speed limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, yes. That's why rockets don't need heat shields on the front on the way up. Spacecraft only need them on the way down because they are using friction with the atmosphere as a way to decelerate; otherwise, they'd need to use just as much rocket fuel on the way down as they used on the way up. While in orbit (or on the way back from the moon, as the case used to be) their speed relative to the ground is extremely high as you inferred.